# use local storage on factory to make CRUD angular

Tags: angularjs

hello i try to learn how to use local storage to make create,update,delete module.
currently i place my data on factory

factory.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Experiences',function(){
    return {
       get: function() {
        return [
            {"id":1,"name": "Implementasi ProMISC","alamat": "Jakarta","bidang": "JASA KONSULTASI NON-KONSTRUKSI","mulaiKerjasama":"03/09/2017","nilaiKontrak":"1000000000","curency":"USD","buktiKerjasama":["note.txt"]},
            {"id":2,"name": "adsdsdsv","alamat": "Jakarta","bidang": "dsudmwisahi","mulaiKerjasama":"04/05/2017","nilaiKontrak":"120503","curency":"IDR","buktiKerjasama":["img.txt"]}
        ];
       }
    };
});
```

experience Ctrl

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ExperienceCtrl',['$scope','Experiences',function($scope,Experiences){
        $scope.title="List Experience";
        $scope.experiences=Experiences.get();

        $scope.deleteItem =function(experience){
            var index = $scope.experiences.indexOf(experience);
            alert("Deleting DATA: "+ index);
            $scope.experiences.splice(index,1);
        };
}]);
```

how to make local storage on factory?
and if i use local factory can i change the json permanently (let's say i delete one data of it)?

thankn you

Comment: Can make it really simple by including [ngStorage module](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) in the app

Comment: when you say local storage what exactly do you mean

Comment: The data in AngularJS services only persist for the life of the application. To have data persist longer than that, use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API),